# Segmented memory management

Tags: memory, virtual, segments

This is a very simple question ! It has to do with a programming challenge where you had to write a virtual machine that is based on a segmented memory model with 16-byte segment size (notation seg:offset). We have also 2 segment registers (cs, ds)! The machine is initialized with cs=0x0 and ds =0x10

http://www.canyoucrackit.co.uk//15b436de1f9107f3778aad525e5d0b20.js

Questions:

1) Why ds = 0x10 (=16) ? Is this arbitrary for the specific virtual machine?

2) If cs=0 and ds = 16, then the data and code segments overlap to each other! How can code segment and data segment overlap?

3) Codes segment and data segment are fixed size (in this case 16-byte)! i thought that their size is dynamic! More generic: when we say "code segment" we mean that we have a dynamic size segment which can be further divided into fixed size small segments?

What am i missing here ??